# Possible change in behavior, change in UDT return calling convention

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, template-specialization

In the following program function `foo` returns a struct template specialization `A<int>`:

```
template<typename T> struct A {};

A<int> foo();

int main() {
    foo(); //MSVC warning here
}

A<int> foo() { return {}; }
```

Visual Studio compiler with the command line flag `/Wall` issues the warning in the place where `foo()` is called:

```
warning C4686: 'foo': possible change in behavior, change in UDT return calling convention
```

According to Microsoft documentation on [Compiler Warning C4686](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4686?view=msvc-170)

> A class template specialization wasn't defined before it was used in a return type.

In my case, struct template is defined before. Only the function itself is defined after (in real life the function is defined in another .cpp file).

GCC and Clang do not see anything bad in the program even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` flags. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1o9cTGn4j

Is there anything wrong with the code? Can the warning be silenced somehow without `#pragma warning(disable:4686)`?

Comment: The linked docs says "This warning is off by default.". I.e. this is probably not relevant... What is your concern?

Comment: *"possible change in behavior"* means that once upon a time the compiler did one thing, and now it does something different. So if you haven't tested you code in 10-20 years, you should rerun your tests - the result might be different. In general /Wall is not useful (except as a one off experiment) - it warns for **a lot** that isn't real errors - like that C++98 is different from C++20. Or that the compiler has removed long standing bugs, and now works properly.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe, many warnings that are disabled by default are very useful and inform us about real problems in the code, e.g. unused variable warning may be a signal that some code is extra or lost. And my concern here is that I do not understand this warning and it looks not related to the official warning's description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/msvc-fails-to-instantiate-stdarray-and-erroneously/1150191

> Using a template specialization as a return type doesn't require its instantiation (and shouldn't, see below). However, the property which impacts the UDT return calling convention is only known after the return type is defined and a template specialization is only defined when it is instantiated.
>
> To fix the warning, you can force the instantiation of the template specialization.

So the solution is to explicitly instantiate the templated return type by adding the following line:

```cpp
template A<int>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and for workaround. Still the answer there does not look correct to me. For example, MSVC compiler does not report the warning in the line `A<int> x = foo();`, but do report in `auto x = foo();`, which must be the same. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/89dqr489b

Comment: Per the documentation for C4686: "A class template specialization wasn't defined before it was used in a return type. Anything that instantiates the class resolves C4686;" I guess `A<int> x = foo();` counts as instantiating since you're explicitly specifying the return type. `auto` involves type deduction and coupled with templated types, you may risk returning a different type from what you actually want, hence the warning.